# Making Google map marker mouse-over more interactive

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map with a google marker, but I would like to do some fun things with it like post a link in there, and format the text there to have an information item per line instead of all in one line.

Is that possible?  If so, then what can be done and how? :)
Here is my current boring map and marker at the bottom of this page:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/trailhead.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
<script...

var marker = new GMarker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker);
var myHtml = "<your html here/>";
GEvent.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
     map.openInfoWindow(point, myHtml); 
};
.../>
```

where

```
<your html here/>
```

is what you want to show, for example image and contact info or something.
That is if you want the info window opened on mouseover event. You could either open it by default by calling that function ( map.openInfoWindow(point, myHtml) ) right away.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When the marker is clicked, it would display a bubble window containing the HTML of your choice (the myHtml variable in this example).

Comment: That do as @Fosco explained, i just edited the code so the event is "mouseover" instead of "click", as you asked in first place.